# Sign with private key and verify with public

Tags: c, windows, openssl, cryptoapi, mscapi

OpenSSL's rsautl allows signing with a private key. This is without a hash. Then recovering the signed file with a public key.

I've looked at `CryptCreateHash/CryptSignHash/CryptHashData` but I'm not sure how to do it. I believe those functions will only sign the hash of the data, not the data itself.

Is there any way I can sign with the private key and no hash involved?

Edit: Made necessary changes from jww's recommendations.

Comment: Don't use `rsa_private_encrypt` and `rsa_public_decrypt`-like functions. Approach signing as signing, and not in terms of things like "encrypt with the private key" (which is ***not*** a valid cryptographic operation). If you want "encrypt with the private key," then you usually want a [Signature Scheme with Recovery](http://www.google.com/search?q="Signature+Scheme+with+Recovery").

Comment: Understood. I don't refer to them that way, it's how they are referred to in rsautl. https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/rsa.html

Comment: Related, see [RSA_public_decrypt and MS Crypto API equivalent](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14527898).

Comment: OK, I found an example of doing it with OpenSSL command line tools. See [OpenSSL and MS CryptoAPI: different digital signatures](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8572986). But I'm not sure if `openssl dgst -sign` calls `rsa_private_encrypt`.

Comment: Thank you so much. I realized why the call to CryptCreateHash was failing. Your post helped me out a lot.